# scripts are being deferred somehow which is breaking parts of my site

Tags: wordpress, jquery-deferred, deferred

Today I noticed the blog section of my site was not rendering correctly, and the console was spitting out errors that I knew where to do with jquery not loading.

When I looked at source code all the scripts that where added by WordPress (wp_enqueue_script) had an extra element added to it, so:
`<script type='text/javascript' src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js'></script>`

become:
`<script type='text/javascript' src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js' defer '></script>`

so 'defer' and a single quote mark is being added.

I need these scripts to load in the , when I register the scripts I do set load in the footer as false.

I'm not sure why/how 'defer' is being added? Or why a single quote mark is also added? I'm also not sure if deferring them is what breaks the page or this rouge single quote mark?

I do use 'Autoptimize' but I have turned it off and cleared out all caches.

The only hack around it, short term, is to hardcode the scripts into the header.php and these are not deferred.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a (badly developed) plugin, disable plugins one by one until the defer attribute goes away. If not it could also be a theme thing, briefly switch to a default WordPress core theme to double-check?

frank